# Programmatically set build description

Tags: groovy, jenkins-workflow

I'm trying to create a git-pull-request-checker with the workflow plugin. Is there a way to set the description for a build (e.g. to `PR#123: fixed a bug`) so that it becomes visible in the list of the previous builds?

Comment: Just curious  - how are you writing the workflow groovy for a pull request checker? Would be super if you could share :-)

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I did. Give me some time to write it down, then I'll link it here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of [1.4](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/CHANGES.md#14-mar-16-2015), try

```
currentBuild.description = 'PR#123: fixed a bug'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot pal! This even works with groovy system scripts.

You can even use `currentBuild.displayName="Something"` while `Thread.currentThread().executable...` fails.

Comment: I know this is very old but when I try this in a build step as ```Execute system Groovy script``` I'm getting the following error has anyone any idea? 

```groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: currentBuild for class: Script1 ```

Comment: This only works from Pipeline script.